# Bayesian statistics for 2 directional tests at the same time

Tags: bayesian

We want to run Bayesian statistics on 2 variables on which the H1 hypothesis to be directional for both of the variables at the same time (ex. A>0 and B<0), while the rest of the case to be H0.

We are not sure what is the best way to do it and would really appreciate if anyone has some experience or could give us a hint on which direction to look at. Would also be fine if one only knows it for frequentist statistics.
Thank you in advance.